# Check if file contains multibyte character

Tags: linux, multibyte

I have some subtitle files in UTF-8. Sometimes there are some sporadic multibyte characters in these files which cause problem in some applications.

How do I check in linux (and possibility locate these) if a certain file contains any multibyte character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use file command

```
chalet16$ echo test > a.txt
chalet16$ echo testก >  b.txt #One of Thai characters
chalet16$ file *.txt
a.txt: ASCII text
b.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way I can locate the offending character?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file` or `chardet` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, chardet or file produce similar results. Is there a way to locate the offending character like ä?

Comment: @MMA You can use `grep -P '[^\x00-\x7f]' input.txt` to locate.