# Trying to remove non-printable characters (junk values) from a UNIX file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, non-printing-characters

I am trying to remove non-printable character (for e.g. `^@`) from records in my file. Since the volume to records is too big in the file using cat is not an option as the loop is taking too much time.
I tried using

```
sed -i 's/[^@a-zA-Z 0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_+\[\]\\{}|;'\'':",.\/<>?]//g' FILENAME
```

but still the `^@` characters are not removed.
Also I tried using

```
awk '{ sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9\"!@#$%^&*|_\[](){}", ""); print } FILENAME > NEW FILE
```

but it also did not help.

Can anybody suggest some alternative way to remove non-printable characters?

Used `tr -cd` but it is removing accented characters. But they are required in the file.

Comment: which language  is used (unix parameter) ?

Comment: have created a normal /bin/sh script in unix box. This script will run over a file with 25 million recrods and fetch data from db too. However the records having junk value is being omitted by this script.

Comment: If you're seeing a lot of NULL (0x00, \0000) characters, it might be some sort of multi-byte encoding.  **If** this is the case, these are not "junk" characters.
The easiest way **I** know of to check is to load the file, or some portion of it, into `emacs`.

Comment: Oop.  I just found this.  I **know** this will be faster than `emacs`.  [Check if file contains multibyte character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373258/check-if-file-contains-multibyte-character)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps you could go with the complement of `[:print:]`, which contains all printable characters:

```
tr -cd '[:print:]' < file > newfile
```

If your version of `tr` doesn't support multi-byte characters (it seems that many don't), this works for me with GNU sed (with UTF-8 locale settings):

```
sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g' file
```

Comment: On mac, you'd need `gsed`

Answer (score 4):

Remove all control characters first:

```
tr -dc '\007-\011\012-\015\040-\376' < file > newfile
```

Then try your string:

```
sed -i 's/[^@a-zA-Z 0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_+\[\]\\{}|;'\'':",.\/<>?]//g' newfile
```

I believe that what you see `^@` is in fact a zero value `\0`.
The `tr` filter from above will remove those as well.

Answer (score 1):

Was searching for this for a while & found a rather simple solution:

The package `ansifilter` does exactly this. All you need to do is just pipe the output through it.

On Mac:

`brew install ansifilter`

Then:

`cat file.txt | ansifilter`

Comment: Works on Linux as well. Thanks! Other solutions didn't work for me, as I wanted to convert string `"\033[?1002l\033[?1000l\033[?1005l\033[?2004h\033[?2004l\033[?1002l\033[?1000l\033[?1005ldebconf:"` (`\033` is escape character, similar to `\e`)

Answer (score 0):

```
strings -1 file... > outputfile
```

seems to work. The strings program will take all printable characters, in this case of length 1 (the -1 argument) and print them. It effectively is removing all the non-printable characters.

"man strings" will provide the documentation.

Comment: This reply is very short and lacks a minimum of explanation, so it is candidate for deletion. Please try to add some more explanation about the command you suggest.