# How to replace non printable characters in file like <97> on linux

Tags: linux, sed, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to remove junk characters from file using sed command.
I tried by using below command but not worked.
sed -i 's/[^[cntrl]]/ /g' 
sed -i 's/[^[print]]/ /g'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to remove non-printable charaters(junk values) from a UNIX file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412754/trying-to-remove-non-printable-charatersjunk-values-from-a-unix-file)

Comment: Does the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412754/trying-to-remove-non-printable-charatersjunk-values-from-a-unix-file) suffice for your purposes? It uses the complement of `[:print:]` with either `sed` or `tr`.

Comment: I have  try with [:print:], but it is not replacing non printable characters like <97>